# How To Fit A Plane To Multiple Points?

Tags: geometry

I need help with plane fit. I am using [this](http://www.ilikebigbits.com/blog/2017/9/24/fitting-a-plane-to-noisy-points-in-3d) as a reference.

I calculated centroid as mean value of each coordinate.

Then I calculated matrix $M$:

$$
M = \begin{vmatrix}
    x_1 - x_c & y_1 - y_c & z_1 - z_c\\
x_2 - x_c & y_2 - y_c & z_2 - z_c\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
    x_n - x_c & y_n - y_c & z_n - z_c \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

Then I calculate my covariance matrix:

$$A = M^T * M$$

and I divide each value in matrix $A$ by $N$ - number of points
then I calculate eigenvector using $eig()$ function in Octave (if that is relevant). My problem is that it leaves me with vector $x$ that has three values so I cannot use this formula to calculate distances:

$$ d = \frac{Ax_i + By_i + Cz_i +D}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + C^2} } $$

I tried assuming that one  of $ABCD$ is equal $1$ but it did not work.

Can you point out my mistake? Or perhaps there is some other, similar algorithm using SVD instead?

Comment: I skimmed through the link you provided, so I'm not 100% certain... but that vector $x$ computed as an eigenvector should be the normal of the plane. So your fitted plane is the plane that goes through the centroid and with normal $x$? You can then compute the values of $ABCD$ from $x$ and the centroid.

Comment: I tried doing it in a way $$A(x-x_c)+B(y-y_c)+C(z-z_c)=0$$ so I get $D$ value from centroid and $ABC$ are values from vector $x$ but still distances are far off. Is there something wrong with my $A$ or $M$ matrices? I apologize, they were displayed wrong earlier.

Comment: Before looking at this in more details, I have one more question. You said you used the `eig()` function from octave, but which variant exactly did you use? I'm not familiar with octave, but if you've simply used `x=eig(A/N)` then `x` contains the eigenvalues, and isn't the eigenvector. If you've used the proper eigenvector, it would also help if you could provide some sample data and the code snippet you're using. At least I don't see any conceptual flaw in the approach, so I'd assume either the code or the interpretation to be faulty here.

Comment: Yes, I think you found the problem. In fact I'm using eigs() function but I don't really know where to go from there. As far as I know Octave syntax is very similar or basically identical with MatLab, perhaps that will help. Here's the code, I hope sample data is enough. I can add more if that helps: https://gist.github.com/PolishJohnWick/102a0617c4bcaacf51836355f9c56b40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a quick look at the [`eig`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/eig.html) and [`eigs`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/eigs.html) function documentation for octave, I have to admit that the `eig` one is a little confusing to me.

Regardless, in the code you linked, you used 
`[x l] = eigs(B);`, which by default returns the six eigenvalues (and corresponding eigenvectors) with `largest magnitude`. In this particular case, it should yield all three eigenvalues, but the documentation doesn't seem to specify in what order these eigenvalues/eigenvectors are returned.

*Maybe* the returned eigenvalues are sorted from largest to smallest, but you probably want to make sure of that somehow. Alternatively, you can just inspect the matrix `l` of eigenvalues to find the good one. Or tweak the arguments of `eigs` to ask for the smallest eigenvalue directly:

`[x, l]=eigs(B, 1, "sm");`

With the selection of the proper eigenvalue/eigenvector out, your code has one more mistake. To quote the documentation:

> [V, d] = eigs (A, …)
>
> ...
>
> With two return arguments, V is a n-by-k matrix whose columns are the k eigenvectors corresponding to the returned eigenvalues.

However in your code you've extracted a line of "`V`" (which you've called `x`):

```
[x l] = eigs(B);

A = x(1,1);
B = x(1,2);
C = x(1,3);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and time!
I have one more question: I've corrected my code using your suggestions, however simply calculating point-plane distances left me with ~69.05 meters distance which was weird. 
I then substracted Centroid distance from each point distance and results are within expectations for me but is it mathematically correct?

Comment: @PolishJohnWick If you've computed $D$ as $$D=A*X_c + B*Y_c + C*Z_c$$ then the equation of your plane is $$Ax+By+Cz-D=0$$ and the distance should be $$d=\frac{Ax_i+By_i+Cz_i-D}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}}$$ What did you compute?

Comment: I just forgot about minus before $D$ value - I was adding it as it is in original formula. Everything works as intended now. Thank you so much for your help!